# Does google analytics work for the app which is not uploaded to the google play store?

Tags: android

I wanna know how to use google analytics for the app which is not uploaded to the play store

Comment: You can honestly try it out yourself to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. It's better to do some R&D before you post the question.[link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

Comment: it didnt work for me after tried a lot thats why i asked .thank you for the answer.

Comment: @ItariumTechnology when have you implemented this? It will take around 12-24 hours for 1st analytic reflection.